# callback_query from telegram (php)

Tags: php, architecture, telegram

I have a working bot that works correctly and processes all callbacks from inline buttons. The problem is that now the processing is done like this (just an example):

```
if ($callback_data == 'save'){
    //some code
}
else if ($callback_data == 'connect'){
    //some code
}
```

Etc. Each if block handles the inline keyboard, and the problem is that their count is increasing. I wanted to ask for advice, how can I refactor the code to avoid a lot of if/else in the future?

Comment: You can use [switch](https://www.php.net/control-structures.switch), or [interface](https://www.php.net/language.oop5.interfaces)/[abstract](https://www.php.net/language.oop5.abstract) (ex: have a "process" method in each class such as Save, Connect, ...)

Comment: Having written a telegram bot before are you asking how to handle the incrementing event calls / loopbacks for edit typing etc?

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of wrappers for telegram bot api. You may use [`westacks/telebot`](https://github.com/westacks/telebot). It allows you to create handler classes which are much cleaner than if/else statements:

```php
<?php

namespace Somewhere\InYour\App;

use WeStacks\TeleBot\Interfaces\UpdateHandler;
use WeStacks\TeleBot\Objects\Update;
use WeStacks\TeleBot\TeleBot;

class YourUpdateHandler extends UpdateHandler
{
    public static function trigger(Update $update, TeleBot $bot): bool
    {
        return 'save' == ($update->callback_query->data ?? null);
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->answerCallbackQuery([
            'text' => 'Saved!'
        ]);
    }
}
```